# Bind control value with property which have List of values. It is possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have windows where I have some controls(time period picker):

*UPDATED*

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}" Name="timeType" />
<Slider Value="20" Minimum="{Binding SelectedItem.Min, ElementName=timeType}" Maximum="{Binding SelectedItem.Max, ElementName=timeType}" Name="timeSlider" />
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=timeSlider, Path=Value}" Name="timeValue" />
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=timeSlider, Path=Minimum}" Name="timeValueMin" />
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=timeSlider, Path=Maximum}" Name="timeValueMax" />
```

In window class I did property:

```
    public class TimePeriodType {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int Min { set; get; }
        public int Max { set; get; }
    }

    public List<TimePeriodType> Periods = new List<TimePeriodType>() { 
        new TimePeriodType() { Name="Hours", Max=6, Min=1 }, 
        new TimePeriodType(){ Name="Minutes", Max=59, Min=20 }
    };
```

And now I want to do somethink to update Slider values when I change value in Groupbox. Is there any possibility to do it?

Already I do it like this:

```
    private void timeType_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
        var period = Periods.Single(p => p.Name == timeType.SelectedValue.ToString());
        timeSlider.Minimum = period.Min;
        timeSlider.Maximum = period.Max;
    }
```

But for me it is not great solution.
Maybe you know simplier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution.
There should be property with get method:

```
    public class TimePeriodType {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int Min { set; get; }
        public int Max { set; get; }
    }

    List<TimePeriodType> _periods = new List<TimePeriodType>() { 
        new TimePeriodType() { Name="Hours", Max=6, Min=1 }, 
        new TimePeriodType() { Name="Minutes", Max=59, Min=20 }
    };

    public List<TimePeriodType> Periods {
        get { return _periods; }
        set { _periods = value; }
    }
```

And in addition there should be following binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Periods, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

*I removed your design attributes to make the solution look a little cleaner.*

Keep your list of `TimePeriodType`s exposed in your code:

```
public List<TimePeriodType> Periods = new List<TimePeriodType>() {
    new TimePeriodType() { Name="Hours",   Max=6,  Min=1  },
    new TimePeriodType() { Name="Minutes", Max=59, Min=20 }
};
```

Make sure your `DataContext` is appropriately set to allow you to bind to members of the backing class you're using.

Then, bind the `ListBox` (or other `Selector` control) to that list:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}"
         Name="timeType" />
```

Now, you can directly bind the properties of the `Slider` to the properties of the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` (which is really a `TimePeriodType` because the of the prior binding):

```
<Slider Maximum="{Binding SelectedItem.Max, ElementName=timeType}"
        Minimum="{Binding SelectedItem.Min, ElementName=timeType}"
        Name="timeSlider" />
```

Finally, you can bind the labels to the values assigned to the `Slider`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=timeSlider}"
       Name="timeValue" />
<Label Content="{Binding Minimum, ElementName=timeSlider}"
       Name="timeValueMin" />
<Label Content="{Binding Maximum, ElementName=timeSlider}"
       Name="timeValueMax" />
```

Comment: Ok. But there in combobox are 6 blank records instead of 2 Names. What should I do to see only names?

Comment: In your `ComboBox`, set the `DisplayMemberPath` to `"Name"`; that instructs the control to use the `Name` property on each item as the display value. Also, I don't know why you have 6 items in the list, if you're binding to a list of only 2 objects... you'll have to debug that further.

Comment: OK. I correct my XAML code in my post. You can look at it. Maybe I did something wrong. I didnt change anything in my c# code except remove method for event SelectionChanged. I tried to binding by DataContext and also ItemsSource but it is the same effect. Really I dont know if there are 6 elements on the list. I cant select anyone. But list looks like 6 empty elements(I mean only height of list - blank white rectangle). I also tried to set DisplayMemberPath="Name" But I had the same effect.

Comment: The only thing I see immediately wrong is that `DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Name}"` should be `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` (it's just a text field, not something that needs to be bound) so the next step would be to add an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is the same as your `ComboBox`'s. `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}" />' This should show you exactly what the `ComboBox` is being bound to.

Comment: Okay, I just reread your previous comment; I think what's wrong is that the initial binding of the `ComboBox` isn't taking because the `DataContext` of the `Window` (or other root element) isn't correct. In the opening tag for your `Window` (or `UserControl`, etc..) add the following attribute: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: Ok. I did it but still it isnt work. It would be better if you give me a xaml code how should looks like this component. Already I have: <ComboBox Name="test" DisplayMemberPath="Name" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}" /> I create a button and on click event I do: this.test.ItemsSource = this.Periods; And this is working. After that the values appears....